# problems with kohana and nginx / php-fpm

Tags: nginx, kohana, php

I'm having issues getting kohana to come up at all. I'm somewhat new to nginx and it's configurations.
It's a CentOS 5.6 box.
The configuration file: http://pastie.org/2499212

I can get phpinfo() to return correctly or other static files. It appears to be choking on the rewrite rules.
BTW, This particular config works with another server and kohana. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If it's the common `route not found` problem, just create a route on your application that matches something like `Route::set('files', 'file/get(/<file>)', array('file' => '.+'))`

Comment: Also specify the Kohana version, as there's always some significant changes even between lower versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line in your configuration

```
# PHP FILES MIGHT BE TO HANDLED BY KOHANA
try_files $uri $uri/ @kohana;
```

doesn't make much sense because you're matching against `.php` files. Kohana doesn't work that way though as it handles URLs which are either like /index.php/controller/action or /controller/action, neither end in .php and thus don't match your rule.

This configuration should work for you:

```
location /
{
    try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
}

location = /index.php
{
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_param KOHANA_ENV production;
    fastcgi_pass php-nolimits-staging;
    track_uploads proxied 30s;
}
```

You can have another location block to match against .php files if you wish, that way you can have static PHP files in your webroot. My configuration is for when Kohana is in the webroot.

Start off with a basic basic configuration ^ and see if works. If you need more help check out #nginx on Freenode.

Comment: What does `fastcgi_pass php-nolimits-staging;` do?